# Using capacitor-community/admob with vue.js and Ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, admob, capacitor

I'm trying to add capacitor-community/admob into my Vue 3 app. Before integrating the ads I thought I'd create the simplest of vue pages to make sure everything works. The problem is I cannot find a simple Vue3 example with capacitor-community/admob to copy. So I used the various other examples given to create a simple page:

```
<template>
<IonPage>
    <IonContent>
        something
    </IonContent>
</IonPage>

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { IonContent, IonPage } from '@ionic/vue';
import { AdMob, BannerAdOptions, BannerAdSize, BannerAdPosition, BannerAdPluginEvents, AdMobBannerSize } from '@capacitor-community/admob';
import { onMounted } from 'vue';


onMounted(async () => {

    AdMob.initialize({
    requestTrackingAuthorization: true,
    initializeForTesting: true,
  });


const options: BannerAdOptions = {
      adId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
      adSize: BannerAdSize.BANNER,
      position: BannerAdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      margin: 0,
      // isTesting: true
      // npa: true
    };
    AdMob.showBanner(options);

    AdMob.addListener(BannerAdPluginEvents.Loaded, () => {
        console.log('Banner ad loaded');
    });

    AdMob.addListener(BannerAdPluginEvents.SizeChanged, (size: AdMobBannerSize) => {
        console.log('size' + size);
    });
    
});
</script>
```

(the adId is the Google banner test id)

Unfortunately no banner ad is visible:

[image: no banner ad]

Here is the console.log:
[image: console.log]

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the warning message says, it no longer works on the web, but only on native platforms.
If you run it with a native build, you'll see that it looks normal.

If you want to create an ads that works on the web, you should use adsense instead of admob.